# mean(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am new in DRL and I want to solve a simple optimization problem using `DRL`, `pytorch` or `tensorflow`. However, I have an error in my code. anybody can help me to debug it. thanks in advance!

```
Error: mean(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not list
```

The code is trying to solve  the following optimization problem:

```
Min  2\*X1^2+4\*X2
subject to X1+5\*X2\>=5
```

I know that better alternatives are available to solve the optimization problem, but it is just an illustrative concept to develop more sophisticated models. More available codes on the internet are using predefined environments. However, here we need to define our own environment.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define a custom Gym environment for the constrained optimization problem
class CustomConstrainedEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomConstrainedEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)

    def reset(self):
        self.state = torch.rand(2) * 2 - 1
        return self.state

    def step(self, action):
        self.state = torch.clamp(self.state, -1, 1)
        x1, x2 = self.state
        objective = 2 * x1**2 + 4 * x2
        constraint = x1 + 5 * x2 - 5

        reward = -objective
        penalty = -1e6 * torch.max(torch.tensor([0.0]), constraint)

        done = False
        return self.state, reward + penalty, done, {}

# Define a neural network model for the policy
class PolicyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_actions):
        super(PolicyModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.mean_head = nn.Linear(64, num_actions)
        self.std_head = nn.Linear(64, num_actions)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        mean = torch.tanh(self.mean_head(x))
        std = self.softplus(self.std_head(x))  # Use the built-in softplus
        return mean, std

    def softplus(self, x):
        return torch.log(1 + torch.exp(x))

# Hyperparameters
learning_rate = 0.001
gamma = 0.99
num_epochs = 500
num_episodes = 100

# Create the custom environment
env = CustomConstrainedEnv()

# Build the policy model
num_actions = env.action_space.shape[0]
policy_model = PolicyModel(num_actions)
optimizer = optim.Adam(policy_model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Training loop
reward_history = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    states, actions, rewards, old_means, old_stds, returns, advantages = [], [], [], [], [], [], []

    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        state = env.reset()
        done = False

        #while not done:
        for _ in range(10):
            action_means, action_stds = policy_model(state)
            action = torch.normal(action_means, action_stds)
            action = torch.clamp(action, -1, 1)

            new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            old_mean, old_std = action_means, action_stds

            states.append(state)
            actions.append(action)
            rewards.append(reward)
            old_means.append(old_mean)
            old_stds.append(old_std)

            state = new_state

        discounted_reward = 0
        advantage = 0
        for t in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
            discounted_reward = rewards[t] + gamma * discounted_reward
            advantage = discounted_reward - old_means[t]
            returns.insert(0, discounted_reward)
            advantages.insert(0, advantage)

        advantages = (advantages - torch.mean(advantages)) / (torch.std(advantages) + 1e-8)

        policy_loss = []
        for t in range(len(states)):
            action_means, action_stds = policy_model(states[t])
            action_dist = torch.distributions.Normal(action_means, action_stds)
            new_action_probs = action_dist.log_prob(actions[t])
            old_action_probs = action_dist.log_prob(actions[t])
            prob_ratio = torch.exp(new_action_probs - old_action_probs)

            surrogate_loss = torch.min(
                prob_ratio * advantages[t],
                torch.clamp(prob_ratio, 1 - 0.2, 1 + 0.2) * advantages[t]
            )
            policy_loss.append(-surrogate_loss)

        policy_loss = torch.stack(policy_loss).mean()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        policy_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Evaluate the learned policy
    total_rewards = []
    for _ in range(10):
        state = env.reset()
        done = False
        episode_reward = 0

        #while not done:
        for _ in range(10):    
            action_means, _ = policy_model(state)
            action = action_means
            state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            episode_reward += reward

        total_rewards.append(episode_reward)

    avg_reward = np.mean(total_rewards)
    reward_history.append(avg_reward)

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Average Reward: {avg_reward}")

# Plot the learning progress
plt.plot(reward_history)
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Average Reward')
plt.title('PPO Learning Progress')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Make sure that the `advantages` variable is not a list. Additionally, you should avoid `for` loops and use vectorized implementation. It will give substantial speed up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to calcaute the mean of list of tensors values
so i think you should try to make a loop to calculate the mean of these values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).